# Can't stop web server in Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am running development web server in Google App Engine Launcher without any troubles.

But I can't successfully stop it. When I am press Stop button, nothing happens.

Nothing adds in logs after pressing Stop.

And after that I can't close launcher.

The only way to close launcher is Task Manager.

Although when I am using `dev_appserver.py myapp` via cmd it is successfully stopped by Ctrl+C.

By the way I am under proxy.

Comment: Try closing any open browser windows running an instance.  Try quitting browser altogether.  You may have a crashed instance, where only task manager can stop it.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. It doesn't work if even any browser wasn't opened.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Windows 8 x64!

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? I was faced the same issue with SDK 1.9.15. Once i upgraded to  1.9.17 Issue solved.

Comment: @NNK I'm using the latest version: 1.9.17.

Comment: It used to happen to me, almost always, when I used to feed too much data into the NDB on my dev app server ( say >600 entities, each with 10+ properties ). I have, since lately, not hit this issue as I had completely changed by NDB design. Another reason, though rare, is when you do not close the dev app server and let it run for weeks  ( hibernate your PC in between but no shutdown ). I used it on Win 7 64 bit. Earlier I had 8 GB RAM; then upgraded to 16 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server) only refers to stopping the launcher from the command line, not from the launcher window:

> To stop the local server: with Mac OS X or Unix, press Control-C or
>   with Windows, press Control-Break in your command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but I think if you overloaded the server by repeatedly pinging the IP, you could crash the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server is crashed because maybe you overloaded it or maybe there's an internal error that can be solved by re-installing the web-server.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue too. It has to do with the application you are running. If you are sure it runs perfectly fine, then it may be over burdening the server in a way. I strongly recommend logging relevant aspect of your code so it displays any issue in the log console. Hope this helps